# Set Nest target humidity via API

Tags: api, nest-api

I can't find anything in the documentation about setting the target humidity of a Nest thermostat. I absolutely have to be able to set the humidity remotely.  Has anyone successfully been able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humidity is not a writeable field.

Answer (score 3):

The details of readable and writable fields are provided in the Nest API reference https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference

1. Blue dotted fields represents **Readable**
2. Red dotted fields represents **Writable**