# Does anyone know how to put in a feature request to make the Nest humidity trait writable?

Tags: nest-api, nest-device-access

This is linked to this previous question:  [Set Nest target humidity via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763868/set-nest-target-humidity-via-api/74328442?noredirect=1#comment131221010_74328442)

Answer (score 0):

The field reflects the value from the thermostat's built-in humidity sensor, the thermostat doesn't have any capability of controlling a humidifer.

Comment: Thanks, but that’s not helpful.  I already knew that - I’m asking how to put in a feature request to make it a writable field, like in the previous API (in which you could assign the new value).

Comment: Oh, and Nest thermostats do in fact have the ability to control a humidifier, only that they made that trait read only in the new API, but was writable in the previous API